# i cant get data from NSArray(contentsOfFile: ) and it's return nil

Tags: ios, swift, nsarray

i have a problem
i want to get data from a plist file and put it to an array variable but it doesnt work

```
  let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "SampleData", ofType: "plist")

    let dataArray = NSArray(contentsOfFile: path!)!
```

and this is my plist Data:
[image]

but it doesnt work and has runtime error for NSArray return nil.

Comment: Well, obviously - if you want to read an array, then there *has* to be an array in the plist, not a dictionary.

Comment: Don't use `NSArray/NSDictionary` in Swift to read a property list file. Use `Data` and `PropertyListSerialization` or – still better – decode the data in structs with `PropertyListDecoder`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found my problem . i have to set root in plist as a Array like the below pic , beacuse NSArray just can put array to a variable and it can't put a dictionary item to a variable:
[image]